Cannot directly showing installed app after successfully compiled in Android Studio
2024-12-19 16:59:30: Launching app on 'vivo V2205'.
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected '('

Open logcat panel for vivo V2205 (10DCAM0EKS000ED)

I've compiled the app on a phone in Android Studio (the app is using Java), but the app I successfuly running is not showing directly in the phone and show /system/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected '('. But this doesn't happen in my friend's PC in same app code, only in my PC.
So how do I solve this to make when the app I compiles and installed, shows directly after successfuly compiled?

That error seems to come from the phone, not from the PC. Have you used on your friend's PC your phone or your friend's phone? Debugging such phone related problems eis difficult. I would use Wireshark and capture the traffic on localhost between Android Studio adb and adb server and see what command AS tries hi execute that fails.

No, the problem is not from my phone, My friend using my phone for debugging in another PC and there are no problem on this

What OS is installed on your PC? Have you tried to fully uninstall Android Studios, Android SDK and all AS user data?

Windows 11. I'm not yet to trying uninstall Android Studio fully. Maybe I will try your solution if there are no alternative solution here

This could be an issue with ADB .
Check the version of ADB in your system and in your friends.
And if you are using the android studios run command to launch the app on device, try once with ADB explicitly.
Let's assume your app's package name is "com.example.myapp" and the main activity is "com.example.myapp.MainActivity". The command to launch the app would be: adb shell am start -n com.example.myapp/.MainActivity
